# A manga about a high school student couple who don't get along in real life but are lovey dovey when they chat via text messages

Tags: mel-kano

It is about an anti-bully high school boy who goes on a website to talk to his online girlfriend. When he talks to her, he completely changes his personality and becomes completely sweet. The two decide to meet up in real life. There and then, they find out that they are in the same class, and that they do not get along at all unless they communicate through text messages, so they are in a cafe looking extremely angry towards each other, but talking very sweet through their phones.

The manga follows the two as they begin dating and the progress of their relationship. The manga also follows another couple where the guy accidentally buy a date from another (I think it was a middle school) girl instead of his dream girl.

I have been trying to find this manga for a while now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Mel Kano**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=4694) maybe? I haven't read it, but your description is pretty close to what I know of it.

> Shinjou Shouryuu is a healthy 17-year-old high-school boy. Many of his kouhai wonder why such a great guy doesn't have a girlfriend. Ask him and he'll tell you that between school, work, and saving his kouhais from bullies doesn't leave him much time to go on dates. So he instead goes online to "F.I.L. GATES". There in the chat room his alter-ego, Kakeru, is infatuated with the girl called Hal. Hal sends a message reminding him that Sunday will be the six month anniversary of when they first met (online) and that she wants to meet him in person! And let's just say it's not your typical first date.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the manga that I've been looking for.